# Batch file closes after a goto command

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

Here's the code

```
@echo off 
color 0a
:user_login
set /p username=What is your username?
if %username% == admin (
cls
 goto admin_request_password
)

echo Incorrect username please try again.
cls
goto user_login

:admin_request_password

set /p Password=What is your Encryption Key?:
if %Password% == ecca1924889236 (
pause
cls
goto admin_menu
pause
 )

echo Incorrect password
pause
cls
goto user_login



:admin_menu

echo Type acct_info for account info.
echo Type site_key for website file manager.
echo type ip_info for your ip info.
echo Type close to close the Net-Sec portal
goto admin_menu_process

:admin_menu_process
set /a choice=Waiting for Request:
if %choice% == acct_info (
cls
goto acct_info ) echo Incorrect term cls goto admin_menu

if %choice%  == site_key (
goto site_key  )echo Incorrect term
cls
goto admin_menu

if %choice% == ip_info (
goto ip_info ) echo Incorrect term 
cls 
goto admin_menu

if %choice% == close (
goto close ) echo Incorrect term 
cls 
goto admin_menu
:ip_info
ipconfig 
pause
cls
goto admin_menu


:acct_info
echo Your username is: admin
echo your password is: ecca1924889236
pause
cls 
goto admin_menu




:site_info
The username is: net-sec
The password is: netsec127
pause
cls
goto admin_menu


:close 
cls
```

Comment: after which goto command does it close?

Comment: The two lines following label `:site_info` have an echo missing. Otherwise the code is quite trivial. You should read `help choice` for a better choice ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- Do not set a variable to `%username%` as that is already an existing system variable.
- Enclose both strings with double quotes in a string comparison.
- Use the `choice` command when you have a known set of choices.
- Try not to include unnecessary labels.

Here is a rewrite of your code to hopefully help you in your scripting exploits:

```bat
@Echo Off
Color 0A

:getName
ClS
Set/P "uname=What is your username? "
If /I Not "%uname%"=="admin" (Echo Incorrect username please try again.
    >Nul Timeout 3
    GoTo getName)

:getPass
ClS
Set/P "password=What is your encryption key? "
If Not "%password%"=="ecca1924889236" (Echo Incorrect password please try again.
    >Nul Timeout 3
    GoTo getPass)

:menu
ClS
Echo [1] Account information.
Echo [2] Website File Manager.
Echo [3] IP information.
Echo [4] Close the Net-Sec portal.

Choice /C 1234 /M "Enter your request"

If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo close
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo ip_info
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo site_info
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo acct_info

GoTo :EOF

:acct_info
Echo Your username is: admin
Echo your password is: ecca1924889236
Timeout 3
GoTo menu

:site_info
Echo The username is: net-sec
Echo The password is: netsec127
Timeout 3
GoTo menu

:ip_info
IPConfig
Timeout -1
GoTo menu

:close 
ClS
Echo Closing...
Timeout 3
```